# How can I create a nested grid in Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, nested, grid, widget, frame

I am using tkinter and trying to put some frames inside a grid of the mainframe.
Inside those frames I want to put new widgets into new grids. But the problem is: tkinter thinks of the rows and columns of the "new" grids still as the ones from the old grid from the mainframe. How can I organize them in a nested grid?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

upper_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, W))
lower_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(N, W))

label_1 = ttk.Label(upper_frame, text="Northwest ").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label_2 = ttk.Label(upper_frame, text="Northeast ").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
label_3 = ttk.Label(lower_frame, text="Southwest ").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
label_4 = ttk.Label(lower_frame, text="Southeast ").grid(row = 0, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `upper_frame` and `lower_frame` are `None` actually, so those labels are children of root window.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please elaborate on that? What do I need to change about the         upper_frame and the         lower_frame so that I can get the program to do what I was imagining?

Comment: Split the line `upper_frame = ttk.Frame(...).grid(...)` into two lines: `upper_frame = ttk.Frame(...)` and `upper_frame.grid(...)`. Same for `lower_frame`.

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the line:

```py
upper_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, W))
```

has the same result as below:

```py
x = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
upper_frame = x.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, W))
```

So `upper_frame` is the result of `.grid(...)` which is `None`.

Using `None` as the parent of a widget will make the widget the child of *root* window. So those labels are children of root window instead of the expected `upper_frame` and `lower_frame`.

You need to split the line:

```py
upper_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, W))
```

into two lines:

```py
upper_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
upper_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, W))
```

Same apply on `lower_frame`.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you very much!